# Cannot not run java applet due to java security

Tags: java, security, applet

I am not able to run demo java applet that come with JDK due to java security. I tried adding that file to Exception Site List but the persists. How do I get it to run?

Comment: Which version of Java do you have?

Comment: I updated the latest java version today itself. There is no medium security level in the update. Only high and very high levels are available. That is leading to the problem.

Comment: If possible, put your java console message. To activate this console: Java control panel / advanced / show console. Then, we could see what is the origin of the error.